# Initialization problem with malloc in C across functions

Tags: c, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation, function-definition, function-call

I'm having trouble understanding why the following code gives a garbage value.

EDIT: I need to use malloc, as it's part of the project requirements. I am well aware that it would be easier without using it, but I can't just not use it.

```
void int_init(int * x) {
  x = malloc(sizeof(int));
  *x = 7; //could be any number, 7 was chosen for fun
}

int main(void) {
  int x;
  int_init(&x);
  printf("X: %d", x); //Should be "X: 7", is actually "X: 1595803432" or other garbage value 
  return 0;
}
```

I'm new to this, so apologies if this question is phrased poorly or is too trivial.

FINAL EDIT: Thanks to Vlad and Avi for helping me out. I may have misread the project description, since it seems like there is no way to use malloc to edit the original value of the variable. In my project, there is a struct that is *associated* with dynamically allocated memory (it contains an array of dynamically allocated structs), but I thought that it wanted us to dynamically allocate the entire struct. I apologize for the mistake, but am infinitely grateful for everyone's help.

Comment: What do you think you are accomplishing by using malloc ??? It has no role in your code except for creating bugs. You have a variable x in main. your pass a pointer to it to a function that discards that value and replaces it with your malloc'ed memory. You set that memory, not affecting your original x, leak that memory and go back to main and print the value of your original, never initialized x.

Comment: Haha, this isn't my actual code, I have a project where the requirements are to have a void function that uses malloc to initialize a struct which is later called by main. However, that code wasn't working because of garbage values, so I made a simplified example of the code so that you guys wouldn't have to look through my whole project, and could focus on this one issue.

Comment: If you need to return a pointer to malloc'ed memory, you can either return a pointer value or transmit it through a parameter with an extra level of indirection. `void int_init(int ** dpx) {   *dpx = malloc(sizeof(int));`    int main(void) {  int *px;  int_init(&px);`

Comment: For`int x`, x was a variable in the function's **stack space**.  However, malloc returns the value representing an address in **heap space**.  They are different thing. To make it work, 1. you can make x a pointer so that it can hold an address value. 2. make sure the address is in the heap space so that you can modify it.

Answer (score 1):

In this function

```
void int_init(int * x) {
  x = malloc(sizeof(int));
  *x = 7; //could be any number, 7 was chosen for fun
}
```

the passed pointer was reassigned with the address of the dynamically allocated memory. So after that the pointer does not pointer to the original variable `x` declared in main.

As a result this statement

```
  *x = 7; //could be any number, 7 was chosen for fun
```

assigns a value to the object in the dynamically allocated memory.

Moreover the function produces a memory leak because the allocated memory was not freed.

If you want to change the original variable `x` declared in main then define the function like

```
void int_init(int * x) {
  *x = 7; //could be any number, 7 was chosen for fun
}
```

Taking into account your comment to my answer it seems you mean something like the following.

```
void int_init(int **x) {
  *x = malloc(sizeof(int));
  **x = 7; //could be any number, 7 was chosen for fun
}

int main(void) {
  int *x;

  int_init(&x);
  printf("X: %d", *x);

  free( x );
 
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Vlad. I would like to change the original x, but I have to use malloc for the project. Is there any way to modify the original while still using malloc?

Comment: @SueDoenimuss The variable x occupies its onw extent of memory and has automatic storage duration. So it has nothing common with the allocated memory.